# How to overload less operator in a template class for sort algorithm use?

Tags: c++, templates, sorting, stl

I have a self-define class using template, like this:

```
template<class T>
class foo 
{
    public:
    T a;
    bool operator<(const foo<T> &f);
    //other functions...
}

template<class T>
bool foo<T>::operator<(const foo<T> &f)
{return a - f.a;}
```

Now, I new some foos and give them value, then I want to sort this array:

```
foo<int>* fp = new foo<int>[3];
//give each element value
sort(fp, fp+3); //run-time error
```

When I use sort function, I got a run-time error.

Did I do something wrong? Please help me.

Comment: I wonder why it results in a runtime error, but in fact your less-than operator is no less-than operator in the STL-sense, since it doesn't realize any strict weak ordering, so in theory `std::sort` is completely free to crash or do whatever rubbish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably like this:

```
template<class T>
bool foo<T>::operator<(const foo<T> &f)
{return a < f.a;}
```

`std::sort` requires that the comparison function (your less-than operator in this case) defines a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). Your implementation does not, because it is possible for both `A < B` and `B < A` to be true.

Answer (score 4):

If T is castable to bool,

```cpp
template<class T>
bool foo<T>::operator<(const foo<T> &f)
{return a - f.a;}
```

will return true always except a == f.a. Maybe you need something like:

```cpp
template<class T>
bool foo<T>::operator<(const foo<T> &f)
{return a < f.a;}
```

Obviously, runtime error occurs because your less operator is incorrect for sort function.

Comment: Yup, Anything equals to zero is false, otherwise, is true, so my less operator is a invalid operator because it returns true for both a > b and a < b. Thank you very much:)