# Operator overloader not making an affect

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, priority-queue

I am attempting to create a class that takes a priority queue and reverses the priorities. I include a `bool operator<()` function as a member function of the class, but no matter how I structure this function, the operator never seems to be overloaded.

Here is my class:

```
template<typename T>
class MinPQ{

public:

    bool empty() const {
        return pq.empty();
    }

    unsigned int size() const {
        return pq.size();
    }

    void push(const T& element){
        pq.push(element);
    }

    const T& min() const {
        return pq.top();
    }

    void remove_min(){
        pq.pop();
    }

    bool operator<(const T& element) const {
        return pq < element;
    }

private:

    priority_queue<T> pq;
};
```

**EDIT**

I also tried changing the overloading function to the following and do not undertsand why that isn't working either.

```
bool operator<(const T& element){
    return this < element;
}
```

Comment: How are you using the operator?

Comment: I've just begun studying priority queues and I thought that if I were to include an operator overloading member function, the priority queue will automatically be ordered in terms of this overloader whenever elements are pushed onto the queue?

Comment: Member operator definitions take as argument (by default) the _class_ type. Your operator is endeavoring to compare a priority queue with an element in that queue. You should compare like things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555891/how-to-overload-less-operator-in-a-template-class-for-sort-algorithm-use
Dunno what you want to use this operator for since comparing queue with element seems to have little or no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator<` is meaningless. The only thing it can do is comparing `MinPQ<T>` object with `T` object. If you want to compare two `T` objects you should do this:

1) If the template type `T` can take only a handful of types, you can write comparison operators explicitly for each of these types:

```
bool operator<(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    return lhs > rhs;
}
```

note: each `operator<` should be a non-member function. Or a member function of class `T` with a single argument.

2) write a comparison functor:

```
template <class T> struct CompareT
{
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs > rhs;
    }
};
```

and then declare `pq` member as follows:

```
priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, CompareT<T>> mq;
```

3) If you want simply to inverse priorities, you could simply use `std::greater` class:

```
priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, std::greater<T>> mq;
```

Comment: Your option 1 was what I itnitially thought of doing, however I get an error thrown saying that it must take only one argument?

I understand option 2 and 3, however in this case I have to do so using a member function

Comment: You can read how to write relational operators here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: I meant that you should write non-member function. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to do so using a member function? I added an edit to my question which is another solution that I do not understand why it is not working.

Comment: try adding `friend` and removing trailing `const` in your `operator<` declaration. In fact, it won't be a member function, but it will be defined inside the class. Why `std::greater` isn't suitable for you?

Comment: `friend bool operator<(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs > rhs; }`

Comment: Option 1 is a bad idea, because you have no control over the types, and one of them might already overload the operator for itself. Options 2 and 3 are the way to go, and in this case option 3 is clearly the best.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Sure, you're right. Especially when T is a built-in type. It simply won't compile.